# Reading a file from command line, name of the file as an argument

Tags: c, command-line, argv, argc

i should open and read this file from passing the name of it as an argument of the command line when i run the program, but it keep going through the same error which is the open failure error i set in my program.The file is the correct folder and i also printed the arguments too see the one containing the name of the program wasn't well stored but it was, it's just the fopen function that fails.. Can anybody help me? 
Here's the code:

```
 int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
if(argc != 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: please insert just the name of the file after the one of the program!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

FILE *foo;
foo = fopen(argv[1], "r");

if(foo == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: failed to open the file\n Argument: %s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
```

here i leave the screenshots

[command line screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8iIY.png)

[how i place the txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E74J4.png)

[its position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VmPt.png)

[the program working properly if not run from the cmd line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EQsW.png)

Comment: What specific value did you use for your argument?

Comment: Since the situation you describe seems impossible, it's likely that what you say you are doing is not exactly what you are doing. You say you passed the right file name and the file exists but you have not shown the exact command line you used nor have you shown a directory listing of that file. You could try using an absolute file path rather than a relative path (which is what you get when you use only the filename).

Comment: "The file is in the correct folder": if you don't add a path, is it in the same folder as the executable? I see nothing else remarkable about your code.

Comment: Is your file is already open in other place? Why not try with different file , or try to hard code the path in the code first ?

Comment: Is your working directory set properly? Do you run your program via some IDE or from command line?

Comment: I checked and the file is not open, it is in the same folder as the executable the usual one! Neither do i see nothing else remarkable and that's kinda frustrating :((

Comment: @usr2564301 It might depend on the environment, whether the path is relative to program directory or current directory from where the command is called.

Comment: I run it via command line...

Comment: Please specify what your current directory is and what you enter as filename.

Comment: You keep _telling_ us what you did but you have not _shown_ us what you did. Try to cut and paste a copy of the console display into the question, including the commands that demonstrate you are in the directory you think you are and the file exists there, along with how you invoked your program.

Comment: okok sorry guys! so i have a Mac and the directory is always the dedug folder of the project which also contains the executable file and what i type from the cmd line is 
    Air-di-Louis:ex3 louisdeidda$     gcc -o prova2 main.c
    Air-di-Louis:ex3 louisdeidda$     ./prova2 ex3.txt
    Error: failed to open the file
    Argument: ex3.txt

Comment: as you can see the argument is received correctly..

Comment: but it works if write the name of the file inside the argument of the fopen function and run the program from the IDE, so for sure the txt file is in the correct place

Comment: I recommended that you **cut and paste a copy of the display into the question**, not in a comment (where it becomes almost unreadable). There's an "edit" button below the question to allow you to do that. Also you did not _show_ us that `ex3.txt` exists where you think it does. You could try `ls` and `cat ex3.txt`. Maybe the IDE's "correct place" for the file is different than you think.

Comment: ok i made it, thank you for your patience

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error: failed to open the file\n Argument: %s\n", argv[1]);`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) when the error is from a system function, suggest calling `perror( "..." );` so both the enclosed text AND the text indicating why the system thinks the error occurred are both output to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `fprintf(stderr, "Error: please insert just the name of the file after the one of the program!\n")`   when a check of `argc` indicates the wrong number of command line arguments. then the error message should indicate the correct way to execute the program,  similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <input file name>\n" , argv[0] );`

Comment: @user3629249 thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem:

[image]

Since you passed just the filename to the program, it looks in its current working directory. And as we see from the `ls` command on the previous command line, there are only two files in the current working directory:
main.c and prova. The file ex3.txt *is not there.*

Based on the screenshots, it appears that the current working directory for these command lines was `~/documents/computer science xcode project/21:12/ex3/ex3`,
but the ex3.txt file is actually in the directory
`<something obscured by pulldown>/ex3-<something>/Build/Products/Debug`.

Apparently the IDE uses that Debug directory, not the ex3 directory,
as its current working directory,
since it manages to find ex3.txt there without requiring you to provide any directory path in front of the filename.